Как сменить цвет обводки DataGridColumnHeader?
Перерыл всё, и не нашёл способа, как сменить цвет обводки DataGridColumnHeader и полоски рядом с ним в DataGrid при перетаскивании:

Если надо, то вот стиль который я использую сейчас
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1A1A1A" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1F1F1F" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#262626"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#8000ff"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>


Оно? Подставьте только везде DataGrid.

Я уже пробовал добавлять в DataGridColumnHeader тригер IsPressed с параметром BorderThickness 0, оно почему то не работает. А при попытке задать HighlightBorder и PART_HeaderGripper в Hidden получаю ошибку MC4011 TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter.
